# Bind N Tables to one GridView Without SQL Joining

Tags: asp.net, sql, facebook, gridview

i have some tables that each one have different columns like this :
[image]

each User ( have ID ) can post to my website and Add some events, so each update goes to related table! but my problem is how show this information only in one `Gridview` .  its something like facebook Timeline that shows your updates sorted by date .
i tried to use SQL join but its not a good way because i have 10 to 12 tables, joining all these tables is time consuming.
i want have a `gridview` that be bind from different tables on sort the information by their date ( each table have a date column )
sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a single datasource for your Gridview, which means you need to join your tables in a single query, or use multiple Gridviews (one per table). I can't see why joining your tables in a query would be more time consuming than any other way you propose, assuming there was a way to do it within the Gridview, you'd just be doing the time consuming task on sort rather than on render.

Perhaps post your query and gridview code for a more specific answer.